# Garbage collection java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

how does the garbage collector in java determine that objects are no longer referenced by the program?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the VM but [there are a number of ways it could be done.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 3):

Check this out.

1. [Easy way to explain how GC works...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623423/what-is-an-easy-way-to-explain-how-garbage-collection-works)
2. [How GC works ?](http://chaoticjava.com/posts/how-does-garbage-collection-work/)

Reference :

**Fig : General Collection of Object**

[image: General Collection]

---

**Fig : Memory Collection of Objects**

[image: Memory Collection]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a previous question on much the same subject: [logic of Garbage collector in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202258/logic-of-garbage-collector-in-java)

The link from there (which I now want to read for myself!) is: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html

Answer (score 1):

JVM maintains a map of all referenced objects.
Every GC cycle (there are a number of GC methods in java, train, mark and sweep etc.) the entire list of object references are traversed (NOTE object references live in stack, data lives in heap) and all the object references that are no longer referenced are marked as ready to be garbage collected/are garbage collected.

This is a simplified way of understanding GC, most developers don't need to know the internals of the GC process though; but it's good to have some understanding.

Here are some links that might interest you:

http://chaoticjava.com/posts/how-does-garbage-collection-work/

http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/ts-3153-coomes-19899-dsf-150093.pdf#search=%22garbage%20collection%22

Hope this helps...

Comment: *"JVM maintains a map of all referenced objects."* - not exactly.  In some cases, the GC effectively *builds* a temporary map of objects copied from the "old space" to the "new space".  In other case, there is only a bit in the object's header to indicate that it is referenced ... and no map at all.

Comment: *"... the entire list of object references is traversed"* - No GC I've ever heard of builds or uses a list of all object references.

Comment: @Stephen C I am sorry for the incorrect information. Your points are valid. "Zach L" please note Stephen's corrections. Thanks Stephen.